# ImportError: No module named pkg_resources when running pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to update my pip, but whenever I run pip I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I've noticed that Python 3.8 is in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions but there is nothing in /Library/Python.